# How to pass value to variable from config file in python

Tags: python, hyperlink, format

I have link.

Like:

```
url =  "https://example.com={}".format(id)
```

i am using in my  main code but i want to store it in config file and pass it "id" in python.
So how can i do that and how do i import it in my code
config = Configuration/config

Comment: Please try and clarify your question. It is very difficult to follow your train of thought here.

Comment: have edit it. actually i having link in my main code, shown above, I want to store it in my config file and want to pass that id veriable so how can i do that

Comment: If I understand you well: you want to "fill" a variable from your config file with a value you get from a script in another file?

Comment: yes, so can you help me in that

Comment: hello guys , can you help to find out any solution for that above question